# In MVC, should the Model or the Controller be processing and parsing data?

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller

Until now, in my MVC application, I've been using the Model mainly just to access the database, and very little else. I've always looked on the Controller as the true brains of the operation, but I'm not sure if I've been correctly utilizing the MVC model.

For example, assume a database of financial transactions (order number, order items, amount, customer info, etc.). Now, assume there is a function to process a .csv file, and return it as an array, to be inserted into the database of transactions.

*I've* placed my .csv parse function in my Controller, then the controller passes the parsed information to a function in the Model to be inserted. However, strictly speaking, should the .csv parsing function be included in the Model instead?

EDIT: For clarity's sake, I specifically am using CodeIgniter, however the question does pertain to MVC structure in general.

Comment: neither.  your controller should call a service where that work is done, collect the results, and return them in a model.

Comment: 'A service'? Could you clarify? I assume you mean an additional library.

Comment: No, a service is a class where business logic is performed.  The controller should just collect data and invoke a service to perform the business logic, then return a result in a model.  Generally speaking, your models should be as dumb as possible; some validation attributes and properties, that's about it.  Likewise, your controller should not be burdened with business logic; it should be concerned with validating models and security, and passing the model to the service.

Comment: Sorry, my question was phrased vaguely - what I mean is, within the context of CodeIgniter, this would be called a library? An additional class that is loaded to handle specific functionality. (For example, form validation is a library that needs to be loaded)

Comment: I haven't used CodeIgniter (you should add that as a tag), but from your description it sounds like a service could be a library... but it's usually something that the developer(s) wrote.  MVC supports SOLID development; it's important to remember the Single Responsibility Principle.  Don't try to make your controller do too much.

Comment: Oh, absolutely, you can write your own libraries for CodeIgniter, very easily in fact. So it sounds like that might be the best solution. Honestly, even regardless of the specifics of MVC, that still sounds like the best solution. Thanks! If you want to leave that as an answer I'll mark it.

Comment: I posted my answer.  Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The internet is full of discussion about what is ***true*** MVC. This answer is from the perspective of the CodeIgniter (CI) implementation of MVC. [Read the official line here.](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/overview/mvc.html)

As it says on the linked page "CodeIgniter has a fairly loose approach to MVC...". Which, IMO, means there aren't any truly wrong ways to do things. That said, the MVC pattern is a pretty good way to achieve Separation of Concerns (SoC) (defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)). CI will allow you to follow the MVC pattern while, as the linked documentation page says, "...enabling you to work in a way that makes the most sense to you."

Models need not be restricted to database functions. (Though if that makes sense to you, then by all means, do it.) Many CI developers put all kinds of "business logic" in Models. Often this logic could just as easily reside in a custom library. I've often had cases where that "business logic" is so trivial it makes perfect sense to have it in a Controller. So, strictly speaking - there really isn't any strictly speaking.

In your case, and as one of the comments suggests, it might make sense to put the CSV functionality into a library (a.k.a. service). That makes it easy to use in multiple places - either Controller or Model.

Ultimately you want to keep any given block of code relevant to, and only to, the task at hand. Hopefully this can be done in a way that keeps the code DRY (**D**on't **R**epeat **Y**ourself). It's up to you to determine how to achieve the desired end result.

**You** get to decide what the terms Model, View, and Controller mean.

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule MVC is popular because it supports separation of concerns, which is a core tenet of SOLID programming.  Speaking generically (different flavors support/ recommend different implementations), your model holds your data (and often metadata for how to validate or parse), your view renders your data, and your controller manages the flow of your data (this is also usually where security and validation occur).

In most systems, the Single Responsibility Principle would suggest that while business logic must occur at the controller level, it shouldn't actually occur in the controller class.  Typically, business logic is done in a service, usually injected into the controller.  The controller invokes the service with data from the model, gets a result that goes into the model (or a different model), and invokes the view to render it.

So in answer to your question, following "best practices" (and I'll put that in quotes because there's a lot of opinions out there and it's not a black and white proposition), your controller should *not* be processing and parsing data, and neither should your model; it should be invoking the service that processes and parses the data, then returning the results of aforementioned invocation.

Now... is it necessary to do that in a service?  No.  You may find it more appropriate, given the size and complexity of your application (i.e. small and not requiring regular maintenance and updates) to take some shortcuts and put the business logic into the controller or the model; it's not like it won't work.  If you are following or intend to follow the intent of the Separation of Concerns and SOLID principles, however (and it's a good idea on larger, more complex projects), it's best to refactor that out.

Answer (score 0):

Back to the old concept of decomposing the project logic as Models and Business Logic and the Data Access Layer.

1. Models was the very thin layer to represent the objects
2. Business Logic layer was for validations and calling the methods and for processing the data
3. Data Access Layer for connecting the database and to provide the OR relation

in the MVC, and taking asp.net/tutorials as reference:

1. Models : to store all the object structure
2. View: is like an engine to display the data was sent from the controller ( you can think about the view as the xsl file of the xml which is models in this case)
3. Controller: the place where you call the methods and to execute the processes.

usually you can extend the models to support the validations

finally, in my opinion and based on my experience, most of the sensitive processes that take some execution time, I code it on the sql server side for better performance, and easy to update the procedures in case if any rule was injected or some adjustments was required, all mentioned can be done without rebuilding your application.

I hope my answer gives you some hints and to help you

Comment: putting business logic on the data server introduces other problems, too.  My general rule of thumb is to *not* do that unless you have a serious performance issue.  Premature optimization makes for a lot more complex, sprawled out code.

Answer (score 0):

If your CSV processing is used in more than one place, you can use a CI library to store the processing function. Or you can create a CSV model to store the processing function. That is up to you. I would initially code this in the controller, then if needed again elsewhere, that is when I would factor it out into a library.

Traditionally, models interact with the database, controllers deal with the incoming request, how to process it, what view to respond with. That leaves a layer of business logic (for instance your CSV processing) which I would put in a library, but many would put in its own model.

There is no hard rule about this. MVC, however it was initially proposed, is a loose term interpreted differently in different environments.

Personally, with CI, I use thin controllers, fat models that also contain business logic, and processing logic like CSV parsing I would put in a library, for ease of reuse between projects.